# Theoretical question: Fetching a 32-bit variable from 128 bit addressable memory

Tags: linux-kernel, c

Suppose I have a processor that is running Linux kernel, and the processor is connected with a 128 bit bus to a memory. The memory is addressed as one address gives you the full 128 bits of data through the bus to processor side.

If I do a 32-bit assignment in the user space:

```
int a = *p
```

where `&p` is pointing to an address in the memory.  That address will return full 128 bits of data through the bus to the processor.

Is the kernel able to translate this kind of access from user space? What would happen?

Comment: Look up virtual memory management

Comment: This isn’t theoretical, it’s how CPUs work nowadays, but the width isn’t the size of the data bus, it’s the size of a cache line. It’s also largely transparent to the operating system and user-space — the ISA directly supports reads and writes of smaller sizes. To cause issues as in your scenario, the ISA would have to only handle 128-bit reads and writes, and then it would be up to the compiler to fix things up.

Comment: A/ Could you specify whether its a 128 bits data or address bus or both ? B/ From the immediately preceding statement (int a = *p) are you sure you actually mean **&**p (in where &p is pointing...) ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OS. CPU registers are still only 32 or 64 bits, and the CPU extracts the appropriate chunk from the bus depending on the instruction that's used.